# Displaying buffer in the desired moment

Tags: c, gtk2

I have a GTK program with a lot of buttons. When I press one of them, my program starts to displaying a buffer, line by line, in this way:

```
  ...
  gchar * stuff = g_strdup_printf("Some text");
  gtk_text_buffer_insert(buffer, &iter, stuff, -1);
  g_free(stuff);
  while (gtk_events_pending())
  gtk_main_iteration();
  ...
```

Because I manage a lot of data, this method is very slow.
I want a second plane mode when some variable reach a high value (for example an int scndplane=1). My idea for this mode is a normal execution of the main program, but to display the buffer only at the end of the program (a kind of backbuffer).

Is there any efficient way to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Why do not you simply make a method of this and then call it at the end of your program ?

If you press your button during the exexution, put a boolean at true.

Then at the end of your program, you will have something along the lines of:

```
if(isClicked) 
  displayBuffer();
```

Comment: That is the question. Keep saving the buffer in second plane and, with a gtk function or something, display the buffer at any specific time. But is there any function or method to do this?

Comment: I used GTK2 and GTK3 and there is not such a function.BUT what you can do is write it yourself.

Comment: Make the function by myself? Any approach or advice to make that? I can't figure out any method.

Comment: I suggest you to accept this answer which answers your initial question, then to write a new post to ask the new one (with more details and code).You can also post it there in the comments, i will look.

Comment: I think what @Keles need is a to run the buffer in another thread or spawn into async process. Both of this approaches are handle by glib functions.